# Need to either match sting or remove unwanted characters from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following variable which is the selected text of a select box. This is the select box markup.

```
<select name="SELECT___100E___7">
<option selected="" value="25">Beige/Almond</option>
<option value="21">Blue [Subtract -$1.00]</option>
<option value="27">Chrome [Subtract -$2.00]</option>
<option value="29">Red [Add $1.00]</option>
</select>
```

Variable test_var hold the selected text...

```
$('select[name^="SELECT___"]').change(function(){
var test_var = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
});
```

So what I would like to do is remove all characters except for the amount, also removing the "$". So if "Red [Add $1.00]" is selected I want to have test_var equal to 1.00

Having trouble figuring out the regexp to do this.

Comment: I hope you aren't using test_var to actually calculate the price of a product.  That could be easily abused.

Comment: Thanks, LOL. No it is does not have anything to do with the actual price of the product in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it (*er, actually, see the update below*):

```
var m = test_var.match(/(-?)\$([0-9\.]+)/);
var result = m.length > 0 ? m[1] : "";
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ataxa4/2)

What that says is "look for a `$` followed by a series of digits and `.` characters, and grab as many of that series as you can when matching." The resulting match array will have the *complete* matching string (including the `$` in position 0, and then the first (and only) capture group at position 1 — and so we grab that.

---

**Update** Er, um, if you need to capture the `-` sign (and I'm guessing you do), change that to this:

```
  var m = test_var.match(/(-?)\$([0-9\.]+)/);
  var result = m.length > 0 ? m[1] + m[2] : "";
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ataxa4/3)

That uses an optional capture for the `-` if it's present before the `$`, and then combines the two capture groups (`m[1]` and `m[2]`; `m[1]` will be "" if there's no `-`).

Results (for example):

```
Red [Add $1.00]        => 1.00
Blue [Subtract -$1.00] => -1.00
```

---

**Off-topic**: Beware localization! Because in some locales, those `.`s will be `,`s, e.g., "€1,00" for one Euro in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a cleaner approach is to simply use a custom attribute:

```
<option value="21" data-amount="1.00">Blue [Subtract -$1.00]</option>
```

Then use `.attr()`:

```
$(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-amount');
```

---

**Original answer:** As [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) noted, this removes the `-`, which is likely needed. If not, this would work.

While you could use a regex, you wouldn't need to.

If you know you'll have that layout of text, you could do something like this:

```
var result = test_var.split('$')[1].slice(0,-1);
```

It will split on the `$`, then remove the last character `]`.

Comment: That will drop the optional `-` (e.g., "Blue [Subtract -$1.00]"). Not sure whether @user wants it, but I'm guessing he/she does as otherwise the amount is a bit misleading. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Very good point. Likely that it is needed. I'll update.

Comment: +1 for the `data-amount`. Although the text is fairly parsable, it's still a cleaner approach and aids localization (you can put "1.00" in the attribute but display "1,00" if that's more appropriate to the locale).

Comment: I wish I had access to the markup to put a custom attribute, unfortunately I don't. Patrick, I really would rather use a a non-regexp solution so I am going to use your answer but since I kinda asked for a Regexp answer I will be polite and give it to T.J.

Comment: @user: Very kind, but just remove the last line of your question and Patrick's answer is just as applicable as mine. Perhaps upvote mine but award him the answer (or don't -- I don't think either Patrick or I is a rep-obsessive :-) ).

Comment: @user - No need to change answers. Future readers will see that there are a number of different ways to approach this. :o)